# Autoloading libraries

Tags: php, autoload

I´m using

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $file_name = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name) . '.php';
    include $file_name;
}
```

to load my classes. And everything is perfect but now I want to use an external library that has a different naming convention  **Services_Twilio** (and I stored the library under /code/twilio/Services/Twilio.php)

Now PHP says **Warning: include(Services_Twilio.php): failed to open stream:**
How can I hanndle these cases? Should I exclude this class? I also found that the library has it´s own autoloader.

Comment: Use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md), it's a PHP project package manager that handles autoloading/etc for all packages.

Comment: it is possible to use composer to load my own libraries? is not getting everything from packagist?

Comment: You'd have to write libraries for composer, you could self-host them though, or pull them off github/gitlab/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the provided autoloader for the package by including it.

Your own autoloader should give their autoloader a chance to act. You should do this:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $file_name = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name) . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file_name)) {
        include $file_name;
    }
}
```

If your autoloader cannot find the file, it does nothing. Therefore the warning you got, will vanish. In addition the autoloader of the package can kick in.

You also might want to consider http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php